# Output a vector of strings before and after 'word' NOT using regex. Making concordance program

Tags: c++, string, vector, return, concordion

I'm working on a concordance program and currently working on the getContext function. I need this function work somewhat like regex, but I want it to return a vector of strings before and after the specified word. I don't know if what I'm thinking about is correct, but it's all that I can think of.

So this is what I had on mind: It takes in a word and creates two vectors and return one the left and right of the specify word.

Thanks. :D

I didn't think I would need to include the whole code file, but if anyone needs it, I can put it up too.

```
/* Get context for input parameter word (case-insensitive comparison)
* Return a dynamically allocated vector of strings, each string
* consisting of contextSize number of words before word and contextSize
* number of words after word, with word in the middle (set off with "<<"
* before the word and ">>" after the word). ContextSize defaults to 5.
* It is user's responsibility to delete the vector.
*/
vector<string>*Concordance::getContext(string word, int contextSize = 5){
    vector<string> before;
    vector<string> after;


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If your question is "NOT using regex", why do you have regex as one of the tags?

Comment: @ken because he doesn't have priviledges to create a not-regex tag

Comment: "I don't know if what I'm thinking about is correct, but it's all that I can think of" ... "A hint or a better explanation than mine would be appreciated".  Ideally you'd know what you want to ask about and have an explanation before asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're just looking for a `std::string` in a `std::vector<std::string>` then you can use `std::find`

```
bool IsWordInArrayOfWords(const std::vector<string>& arrayOfWords, const std::string& word)
{
    auto found = std::find(arrayOfWords.cbegin(), arrayOfWords.cend(), word);
    return found != arrayOfWords.cend();
}
```

If you're looking for a way to search for a partial match of a word and best match based off a percentage or some other more complex context and regex is not an option then I think we'd need a much better description of what you're trying to accomplosh and what the real problem your looking to solve is.

Comment: I'm working on a concordance program and currently working the getContext function. Sorry about that.

Comment: And I wanted to return the vector of strings also.

Comment: I wasn't attempting to write whatever unknown functionality you need for you, just showing one way of finding strings. Having a program with a class named `Concordance` and a function named `getContext` is pretty meaningless without more detail. From the code comment above I can assume this is some kind of badly formed homework.